# Calling a CoffeeScript function across all views (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

this is my first StackOverflow question, so I hope I ask it right!

I have a Ruby on Rails web application where in our javascript files, I have the following CoffeeScript code, which detects when a button with id="submit" is pressed and then scrolls to the first error that appears, if any (the "submit" buttons are used in our forms):

```js
@scroll_to_error = ->
  document.getElementById('submit').onclick = ->
   if $('.alert-danger:visible:first').length > 0
      $('html, body').animate { scrollTop: $('.alert-danger:visible:first').offset().top - 220 }, '1000'
   return
```

I have the file included in our application.rb file in the config folder, so that it can be called in any HTML file in the views section ~~ however, I was wondering if there were a way so that it can be called in all the views that I have. Is there a certain way to do this?

Hope this is suffice info - sorry I could not provide more code snippets, as I am coding for a company (hence the "our").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this?

```coffee
scrollToError = ->
  $('*[data-scroll-to-error="true"]').click ->
    alertElement = $('.alert-danger:visible:first')

    if alertElement.length > 0
      $('html, body').animate { 
        scrollTop: alertElement.offset().top - 220 
      }, '1000'

# Run with turbolinks.
$(document).on 'page:change', scrollToError
```

and a submit button with the `data-scroll-to-error` attribute set.

```html
<input type="submit" data-scroll-to-error="true" />
```

I find this statement of yours confusing:

> I have the file included in our application.rb file in the config
>   folder, so that it can be called in any HTML file in the views section

Assuming this is a standard Rails project, you should have included the file containing the Coffeescript code in `assets/javascripts/application.js` (the manifest file), and since `application.js` is the JS file required in the layout (isn't it? :-/), this code would execute on all of your views. I don't see how `config/application.rb` is involved here.

**Update:** Adding more information.

If you're unsure about how to `application.js` file (a manifest file) is used, please take the time to go through Rails' official documentation about it (especially the section about manifests).

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives

In your case, you'll want to modify `application.js` to include:

```
...
//= require error
...
```

Basically, you list all the asset files that you want loaded along with all pages that use a layout (probably `application.html.erb`), and then mention only the manifest file the layout. That way, Rails can concatenate and minify to generate a single asset file. The default `application.` manifest files are automatically precompiled - so you don't need to manually add new assets to the precompile list.

The reason why I wrote the selector as `*[data-scroll-to-error="true"]` was personal preference - the code reads better to me that way. If you're sure that the ID `submit` is (and will be in future) applied only to elements that require scrolling to error, then it's fine to change the first selector to `$('#submit').click ->`

Comment: There is an application.js file, however I am not quite sure how to include the function to be honest. The function is scroll_to_error, and the file is located in assets/javascripts/error.coffee.

As for the config/application.rb file, it is included using config.assets.precompile

Comment: Also, I am actually coding on a database that is for a company ~~ and there are thus too many buttons already to change all of the data-scroll-to-error to true

Comment: @keyan.r I've updated the answer to include more info related to your comments.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to expose your code in a function so you can call it from the views.

**Coffeescript file:**

```
window.SomeNamespace ||= {}
window.SomeNamespace.scroll_to_error = ->
  document.getElementById('submit').onclick = ->
    if $('.alert-danger:visible:first').length > 0
      $('html, body').animate { scrollTop: $('.alert-danger:visible:first').offset().top - 220 }, '1000'
```

**View file:** (say you are using erb)

```
<script>
  $(function(){ 
    window.SomeNamespace.scroll_to_error()
  });
</script>
```

A better way to do this, however, is to separate view code and javascript code. [elementaljs](https://github.com/elementaljs/elementaljs) offers a small Javascript behaviors library for Rails, which I like a lot. You can "attach" a javascript behavior to a specific html element via `data` attribute, and the library does the above work for you.

Comment: Thank you - however I need this function called automatically in all the views, as manually adding it to each view is tedious, and if other views are added the team I am working with will have to remember to add more. :/

Comment: Even easier! Just say `#= require <insert_relative_file_path>` in your `application.js` and in your coffeescript file put your listener without wrapping it into named function, i.e. `$ ->  document.getElementById('submit').onclick = -> ... ` This code will get run on load of each page.

Comment: Oh, awesome! However, this is the same as using
$(document).ready ->
I kind of want it so that it will get run not only on the load of the page, but also while the user is browsing (say the user clicks a #submit button again and gets another error)

Comment: If I can, for example, call it on every page with <%= f.submit %>, as long as the user is on the page, that would be good, or if I can call it after <%= f.submit %> by modifying the <%= f.submit %> function itself, that would work too

(f being a form, and unfortunately each form has a different id, however, they do have classes .btn and .btn-primary)

Comment: Have you tried it? This would set *listener* on page load, and the code inside listener will run every time the element is clicked. I guess I'm not understanding your point.

Comment: Yes -- now I have
" //= require errors "
in my application.js, and also my errors.coffee now has:
$ ->
  ('#submit').click = ->
(a slight modification was made), and now it does not work at all :(

Comment: Ah - I realized Ajax calls were getting in the way ~ much thanks!